# Tables in Gherkin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to compare between two tables and test the results using Gherkin but I don't know how to make it declare two lists in the @when section instead of one, like how it is shown below:

```
@When("^the integer table :$")
public void the_integer_table_(List<Integer> comp1, List<Integer> comp2)  {

    for(int i = 0; i < comp1.size(); i++) {
        compare[i] = comp1.get(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < comp2.size(); i++) {
        compare2[i] = comp1.get(i);
    }
    comparer.comparer_tableau( compare, compare2);
}
```

Here is my .feature file:

```
  Scenario: Compare the elements of two tables and return a boolean table as a result
    Given I am starting a comparision operation
    When these two integer table are entered :
       |1|2|3|4|5|
       |0|2|5|4|5|
    Then I should see the correct answer is:
       |false|true|false|true|true|
```

Here is what I get when I run it:

```
@When("^these two integer table two are entered :$") public void these_two_integer_table_two_are_entered_(DataTable arg1) { }
```

P.S: I did try and look for solutions but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the step definition as given below and get the values of each row then compare it.

```
    @When("^these two integer table are entered :$")
    public void these_two_integer_table_are_entered(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
       List<DataTableRow> lstRows=arg1.getGherkinRows();

       Integer[] compare=new Integer[lstRows.get(0).getCells().size()];
       System.out.println(compare.length);

       Integer[] compare2=new Integer[lstRows.get(1).getCells().size()];
       System.out.println(compare2.length);

       //Get the first row values
       for(int i = 0; i < compare.length; i++) {
          compare[i] = Integer.valueOf(lstRows.get(0).getCells().get(i));
          System.out.println(compare[i]);
       }

      //Get the second row values
       for(int i = 0; i < compare2.length; i++) {
          compare2[i] = Integer.valueOf(lstRows.get(1).getCells().get(i));
          System.out.println(compare2[i]);
       }
       comparer.comparer_tableau( compare, compare2);
  }
```

AFAIK, You can have only one table per step. But can get the each row values inside your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber will interpret your `When` step to use one DataTable

```
When these two integer table are entered :
   |1|2|3|4|5|
   |0|2|5|4|5|
```

Instead of trying to enter two tables in one step, try entering them in two separate steps (one table per step) like this:

```
When the following integer table is entered :
   |1|2|3|4|5|
And the following integer table is entered :
   |0|2|5|4|5|
```

Comment: I've tried that one but it didn't work either. I think it is like what @Murthi said: You can have only one table per step.

Comment: Which is why I'm suggesting to split your step into 2 steps with one table each.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a scenario outline like this and handle the log to retrieve values for each column in step definition. (split value string by comma and use values accordingly).

```
Scenario Outline : Compare the elements of two tables and return a boolean table as a result
Given I am starting a comparision operation
When integer '<table1>' values are entered
When integer '<table2>' values are entered
Then I should see the correct '<answer>'
  Examples:
  |  table1   | table2    |  answer                    |
  | 1,2,3,4,5 | 0,2,5,4,5 | false,true,false,true,true |
```